# Add column to database without defining it in model with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Is it possible to add a column (or execute some SQL) to a table when Entity Framework is instantiating a new database, without defining it in the Model used in DbSet ?

Iam building a prototype for a SaaS application with Entity Framework and Elastic Scale Client, and want to use Row Level Security, for that a need a column to identify my tenants. So i figured it would be nice if I could use just the EF initializer to add this column, when adding new tenants to the system.

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of it. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Tschallacka : Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2), you can execute sql when you have the DBContext.

From the docs:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
}
```

You could use this to modify the structure without having the actual structure defined in EF.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was hoping there was a way of doing this without having to execute raw SQL. But I ended up using some reflection to get table names from my Context and generating the SQL string to execute. Actually a nice solution (I think :)) as i have to execute SQL statements in order to implement the row level security on the same tables. I guess i was just too hooked up by the idea the hole thing should be managed by EF :)